# Extract files based on the prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to extract filenames from a folder where I can manually select the path and all the filenames and the date of modification is extracted. However, I want a to modify the code so that it extracts filenames of only those files which starts from Alphabet "A". Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant

Dim ShellApp As Object
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set ShellApp = Nothing

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\rd4470\Documents\Test Folder")
i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.DateLastModified
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
    Exit Function
Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume objFile.Name returns a string of your filename? You would just need to surround the innards of your for loop in an if, checking if the first character is an 'A'. (I believe this is what you wanted)...

```
Dim tempString As String

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    tempString = left(objFile.Name, 1)
    If tempString = "A" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.DateLastModified
        i = i + 1
Next objFile
```

code to specify folder:

```
Private Type BROWSEINFO
  hOwner As Long
  pidlRoot As Long
  pszDisplayName As String
  lpszTitle As String
  ulFlags As Long
  lpfn As Long
  lParam As Long
  iImage As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SHGetPathFromIDList Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
            "SHGetPathFromIDListA" (ByVal pidl As Long, _
            ByVal pszPath As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SHBrowseForFolder Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
            "SHBrowseForFolderA" (lpBrowseInfo As BROWSEINFO) _
            As Long

Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
Public Function BrowseFolder(szDialogTitle As String) As String
  Dim X As Long, bi As BROWSEINFO, dwIList As Long
  Dim szPath As String, wPos As Integer


With bi
    .hOwner = hWndAccessApp
    .lpszTitle = szDialogTitle
    .ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS
End With

dwIList = SHBrowseForFolder(bi)
szPath = Space$(512)
X = SHGetPathFromIDList(ByVal dwIList, ByVal szPath)

If X Then
    wPos = InStr(szPath, Chr(0))
    BrowseFolder = Left$(szPath, wPos - 1)
Else
    BrowseFolder = vbNullString
End If
End Function


' insert code anywhere to call function

tempFilepath = BrowseFolder("Choose Folder For Import") & "\"
    If tempFilepath = "\" Then
        MsgBox "No output path specified, please select a valid output path"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: In the above code, I have the path which is pre-entered. Is there a way where I can get a pop up box where I can either select the Path or a text box which takes the path as input and then lists all the filesnames and the date modified?

Comment: Code was copy pasted from one of my old projects, hopefully it can just be copy pasted. It gives you a filepath to a directory in the tempFilepath variable.

Comment: I tried to copy paste and then call the function but did not work. :(

Comment: What's going wrong? did you paste the bit at the bottom? This will error out if you don't put it in a sub or function. And I believe this should be placed at the top of your code.

Comment: Nothing happens. I have pasted the code at the top and then run it. I dont get any option where it asks me to browse any folder.

Comment: Did you use the code at the bottom? You should read the code more carefully and actually try calling the functions. you need to replace the contents of your objFolder string with the results from the browseFolder function call.

Comment: I tried both infact. Pasted the code at the bottom and at the top. Can you please let me know or give the consolidated code? I mean both together?